# Copy row from dataTable to datarow and then to another dataTablein vb.net

Tags: vb.net

How to transfer a row in dataTable to a datarow and then pass the datarow to a new dataTable

```
Public function fn_transfer(dt as dataTable) 

Dim dtNew as new dataTable

dtNew = dt.Clone()

For i as integer= 0 to dt.rows.count -1 

If dt.rows(i)("name").ToString.trim = "" or 
dt.rows(i)("street").ToString.trim = "" then

Dim dr() as new datarow
For each dr in dt.rows(i)
dr = dt.Rows(i).Itemarray

Next


dtNew.importrow(dr(0))

Next
```

This code is not working. Kindly rectify the code.

Comment: Your code makes little sense as it is. You NEVER assign to the loop control variable in a `For Each` loop, for a start. You also never create a `DataRow` directly, but rather let the `DataTable` it will be part of create it. What you have there is what happens when you write code without knowing what it is supposed to do first, i.e. the logic that the code needs to implement. You should take the time to work out the logic first, then write code to implement that logic. If you do that, you should be able to point to the specific logic each line of code is supposed to implement.

Comment: Given that `ImportRow` does all the work of copying data from a row in one table to a row in another table, assuming that your tables have the same schema, everything other than a single loop and a call to `ImportRow` is doing nothing useful.

Comment: Why you don't simply use `Dim dtNew as DtaTable = dt.Copy()`? You want to import only those rows which `Name` or `Street` is empty?

Comment: @tim schmelter  yes only rows with empty values

Comment: Where is the `End If` statement?

Comment: @user17922293 yes I'm aware it's not useful. Hence I asked for help here. So if u have any idea on how to code this problem statement please do so would be great help!

Comment: It would be easier to just use a data view to filter for rows with an empty name..

Comment: @muriel: undeleted. Thought it was not helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So you want to import only those rows which Name or Street is empty?

If you want to use a loop this should work:

```
For Each r As DataRow in dt.rows
    If String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field(Of String)("Name")) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field(Of String)("Steet"))
      dtNew.importrow(row)          
    End If
Next
```

Another way is to use LINQ and `CopyToDataTable`:

```
Dim dtNew as DataTable = dt.Clone() ' empty table with same columns
Dim filteredRows = dt.AsEnumerable().
    Where(Function(r) String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field(Of String)("Name")) OrElse String.IsNullOrEmpty(r.Field(Of String)("Steet"))).
    ToList()

If filteredRows.Any() Then dtNew = filteredRows.CopyToDataTable()
```